# How to escape Salesforce search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, salesforce

I'm using the [Salesforce ruby gem](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) to do the following

```
@client.search("FIND {#{@email}}")
```

`@email` returns the user's email address. During testing, I had an email address like `test+test@example.com` and this caused a MALFORMED_SEARCH error. I tried calling `to_json` on the email, but that didn't fix it. What kind of escaping should I be doing here? Is there a generic way to do this? (I'd like to avoid escaping specific characters like '+')

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [SOSL specification](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm), + is a reserved character and has to be escaped with a backslash. All the characters that need to be escaped are `? & | ! { } [ ] ( ) ^ ~ * : \ " ' + -`

Answer (score 0):

To escape those characters, you can use the following `gsub`:

```
"email+special@example.net".gsub(/(\?|&|\||\!|\{|\}|\[|\]|\(|\)|\^|\~|\*|\:|\\|\"|\'|\+|\-)/){|special| "\\" + special }
```

Original answer: [Escape special characters in ruby string to match Salesforce SOQL requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44705778/escape-special-characters-in-ruby-string-to-match-salesforce-soql-requirements/44707075?noredirect=1#comment76440386_44707075)