# Escape special characters in ruby string to match Salesforce SOQL requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, salesforce

I am developing a Salesforce integration for a Rails application and I ran into an issue of searching/submitting contacts with emails that include special characters like '+'.

Within the Salesforce documentation, they mention that some characters are reserved and a '\' needs to be inserted before each reserved character. Details: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm

Given that a '\' is used to escape characters in Ruby, I have not been able to add the '\' to a reserved character without running into issues with the Salesforce API. For those who have implemented a Salesforce integration for Rails, how did you solve the issue of reserved characters within emails? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape special characters `? & | ! { } [ ] ( ) ^ ~ * : \ " ' + -` in your string like this

```
"email+special@example.net".gsub(/(\?|&|\||\!|\{|\}|\[|\]|\(|\)|\^|\~|\*|\:|\\|\"|\'|\+|\-)/){|special| "\\" + special }
```

Comment: Thank you! it helped a lot!

Comment: I am happy to assist you